# In Magento 2, what is the correct way to override adminhtml emails?

Tags: magento2, email

I want to override a Magento 2 email in adminhtml, has anyone done this already and what is the correct way to do this?

I have tried it like this: `app/design/{vendor}/{theme}/{module}/email`

Thank you!

Comment: Which email template you need to override?

Comment: A custom module's adminhtml email file

Comment: Add your custom module path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out myself!

1) I have created a custom module:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Magento/luma</item>
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/backend</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

2) in CLI use `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade`

3) After creating the module itself i have created the adminhtml folder:

```
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/backend/registration.php

<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Vendor/backend',
    __DIR__
);

app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/backend/theme.xml

<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Vendor backend Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

4) And in the custom adminhtml folder you can now rewrite anything, i made a rewrite for the following file like this:

```
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/backend/Module_Name/email/tracking.html
```

Answer (score -1):

There a way to customize an email template, that is using **Magento Admin - Email Templates**

You can refer to this link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#customize-email-admin

Comment: Hi Walish Le, thank you for your response, i am aware of the way of editing like that. But i want to override the file, so that it wont be in the system but in the file structure.

Answer (score -1):

See my below example for override email template

For Example if you want to override customer new account email template

Copy email template from

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/account_new.html

to

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Customer/email/account_new.html

Comment: Hi S H Patel, thanks for your response but this is for overriding frontend templates, not adminhtml templates right?