# Magento2 - override extension template

Tags: magento2, php-7

The project using an extension called '`Amitshree`'. I need to override an `email template file (filename.html)` created in this extension in my project.

I need a step by step solution because I am not a Magento Developer.

I went through some solutions in this platform, but couldn't resolve my task.

**Edited :**
The following are the changes made in the files.

```
1. Copy the account_approval.html file from Amitshree/customer/view/adminhtml/email to app/code/project/tradeusers/view/frontend/email
2.The following line of code added in app/code/Project/Tradeusers/etc/email_template.xml

<template id="amitshree_customer_account_approved" label="Account activation confirmation for Trade user from Admin" file="account_approval.html" type="html" module="Project_Tradeuser" area="frontend"/>
```

But still the template loaded from extension only.

Comment: which module of Amitshree are you using and which html file you want to update, add all code in question if posible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to override template files for magento2 extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension)

Comment: @Hiren Ir's email module and file is account_approval.html

Comment: This post will be helpful on ovreriding adminhtml email template https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180697/in-magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-override-adminhtml-emails